# Server software to control clients

Tags: windows, linux, networking, server

I have about six client PCs and I would like to manage these in such a way that I can enable/disable their system access in general. For example:

Each client PC shall only be allowed to use Paint and Thunderbird (but each installed software should be able to swichted on/off individually on the client PCs). No shutdown, restart, update control and stuff like this is available for the customer.

Is there a software to handle this or can you tell me how to look for something like that? Open source or commercial is both fine, depends on the advantages in both cases. The clients will use Windows but the server may use linux. I prefer linux but Windows is also ok since the clients are forced to run on Windows.
The best case would be to manage all the clients and their programs from one server. A GUI is necessary.

Thank you in advance